# Different URL in IE11 and Chrome - Office files are not editable

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-chrome, microsoft-word, sharepoint, internet-explorer-11

We are facing the issue on SharePoint (on-premise) in IE11. We can't edit files like Excel, Word ( in desktop version ). We are able to download them and edit them offline. We are also able to open and edit them in Chrome. So the issue is related to IE11. We found out that URL of mentioned files are different in both "browsers" as following:

**Encoded URL**

- <URL>/INDEXACE%202019/indexy%20statistick%25FDch%20%25FA%C5%99ad%C5%AF%20pro%20rok%202019.xlsx?web=1 (**IE11**)
- <URL>/INDEXACE%202019/indexy%20statistick%C3%BDch%20%C3%BA%C5%99ad%C5%AF%20pro%20rok%202019.xlsx?web=1 (**Chrome**)

**Decoded URL**

- <URL>/INDEXACE 2019/indexy statistick%FDch %FAřadů pro rok 2019.xlsx?web=1 (**IE11**)
- <URL>/INDEXACE 2019/indexy statistických úřadů pro rok 2019.xlsx?web=1 (**Chrome**)

[One of recieved errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDPoZ.png)

Comment: It's the similar problem as this -> https://superuser.com/questions/1416966/url-encoded-slash-in-url-failing-in-non-browser-links

Comment: It's look like the issue related to KB4489873 - Cumulative security update for Internet Explorer: March 12, 2019 - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4489873/cumulative-security-update-for-internet-explorer-march-12-2019

But their solution doesnt't work.